# How to translate “就这么着吧”？

Tags: translation

普通话口语里常用。语境：

- 女性跟闺蜜抱怨丈夫：「虽然我跟你这么抱怨，但真要和他离婚也不现实，唉，**就这么着吧**！」（带着点无奈，日子凑合过的味道）
- 论坛网友：「反正不管我再发布多少次，网站都会给我删除的，所以**就这么着吧**，我也没辙」（虽然不接受，但是也无可奈何的意思：不然我能咋办呢？）

网上搜到一些翻译，感觉味道不太对：例如Alright，如果没有音调的辅助，只凭文字传达，Alright没有“就这么着吧”里面的无奈感吧？

所以，怎么翻译好呢？

Edit: In this context, 就这么着吧 means 1) we disagree or dont want sth in heart or at first, 2) but have to accept it in reality or now, because we have no choice and nothing more we can do.

Comment: 另外挺有意思。把“吧”字去掉：「我说什么就是什么，按我说的办，就这么着！」无可奈何、无奈的感觉，立刻就消失了，变成强势的味道。这题请教的是，带上“吧”字，怎么翻译？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **so be it**
>
> used for saying that you accept a situation in which something has
>   been decided or is necessary, although you are not happy about it

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/so-be-it

Comment: "so be it" seems to be the right phrase for it.

Answer (score 1):

Give it another thought:

It seems there isn't a direct phrase or sentence that could work well in all contexts. We should interpret it based on context. It could be "*that's that", "that's how it is", "that's what it is", "that's how it works", etc*. E.g.

> 论坛网友：「反正不管我再发布多少次，网站都会给我删除的，所以就这么着吧，我也没辙」（虽然不接受，但是也无可奈何的意思：不然我能咋办呢？）

In this case, 所以就这么着吧，我也没辙 could be: *so that's how it is*/ *that's how it works*. *I can do nothing about it*.

Answer (score 0):

这么着好。
It's better this way.
这么着怎么样?
How about this?
你要这么着，我就将死了。
You do that and I'm a dead duck.

就这么着吧。
Do it like this.

In your context:

虽然我跟你这么抱怨，
Even though I complain that much,
但真要和他离婚也不现实，
I don't really want a divorce,
唉，就这么着吧！
no, that's how it is!

The question is: should we say zhe or zhao for 着？I get conflicting answers!

Comment: It's Zhao. "That's how it is" seems to be spot on for this context. How about "that's that"?

Comment: Zhao  1. It's what it is. - How do you think of?  2. How about "that's it"?

Comment: Also, I think we could translate, in this specific context: I don't really want a divorce, no, that's the truth of it!

Answer (score 0):

What about [let it be](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+it+be)? According to this link, it means to leave something as it is because there's not much you can do about it. But I am no native speaker and hopefully someone can confirm this.

Comment: In this context, it means 1) we disagree sth in heart or dont want sth at first, 2) but have to accept it in reality or now, because we have no choice and nothing more we can do. Any translation can include these two meanings?

Comment: @SeniorTame "We have to leave it there" could meet these two aspects I think. "have to" denotes unwillingness and "leave it there" accept current solution because we can't come up a better one as yet.

Comment: @SeniorTame I think it depends on how you include the phrase in a sentense. For example, your first example sentence: "Even with all this complaining, I can't just divorce him. Maybe I should just let it be." and for the second: "No matter how many times I repost the site is gonna delete it anyway. I'll just let it be, since  there's nothing I can do."

Answer (score 0):

Let it be 应该是由他去吧.
就这么着应该是 so be it!

Answer (score 0):

how about this one: "that's how it be"

Answer (score -1):

就这么着吧:let it go
就这么着: that's it

Answer (score -1):

> [着](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/1132/) [verb particle] indicating the continuation of an action or a state
>
> Example:
>
> 走 = walk
>
> 走着 = walking
>
> 看 = watch
>
> 看着 = watching

Base on the context, a verb is seemingly omitted in "就这么(?)着吧". The omitted verb could be the following:

"就这么(保持着)(現狀)吧

"let's just (maintaining/ keeping) (the current situation) like this"

"let's just (keeping) (it) at that"

*"Just let it be" would be a good translation too*

Comment: I really don't think your logic applies here. 就这么着 Is just a common expression, your interpretation 就这么(保持着)(現狀)吧 strikes me as both unnatural and unnecessary.